# Pass generic type from a dictionary of types to generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have a large number of Forms that all derive from a base class called `FormBase`. To activate/show them I use the following generic method:

```
public T ShowForm<T>() where T : FormBase, new()
{
     FormBase form = _activeForms.FirstOrDefault(f => f is T);

     if (form != null)
         form.BringToFront();
     else
     {
         form = new T();

         IListView view = form as IListView;
         if (view != null)
             view.ParentView = this;

         _activeForms.Add(form);
         form.MdiParent = this;
         form.Show();
     }

     return (T)form;
}
```

Now I'd like to use a dictionary so that I can easily add more Forms to the mix without having to maintain a giant `switch` statement.

Is it possible to have a dictionary like `Dictionary<string, Type>` and pass Type to the generic method somehow?

Comment: Do you need to `Dictionary<string, Type>` or `Dictionary<string, FormBase>`?

Comment: What do you need the dictionary for?

Comment: I use a rather large `switch (key)` statement which takes the `key` and basically translates it to `ShowForm<FooForm>();`. If I could use a dictionary I'd just have to add `key` and `typeof(FooForm)` to the dictionary to handle the new Form in my code.

Comment: Why not have a `Dictionary<string, Func<FormBase>>` ? You would fill it once with code like: `dict.Add("Foo", () => ShowForm<FooForm>());`

Comment: Thank you Lasse! This a very good approach for this as I have another type of form which needs to be handled by a different function. I think you might have just cut my code by a third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that this is the case, when generic method should wrap non-generic one. Consider this code:

```
    private FormBase ShowForm(Type formType)
    {
        FormBase form = _activeForms.FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetType() == formType);

        if (form != null)
            form.BringToFront();
        else
        {
            form = (FormBase)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);

            IListView view = form as IListView;
            if (view != null)
                view.ParentView = this;

            _activeForms.Add(form);
            form.MdiParent = this;
            form.Show();
        }

        return form;
    }

    public T ShowForm<T>() where T : FormBase, new()
    {
        return (T)ShowForm(typeof(T));
    }
```

Then, when form type is unknown statically, you can call non-generic version of your method:

```
var form = ShowForm(typeof(SomeForm));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine. It seems like I was thinking a little too complicated here. A generic method isn't really needed if I can just use the ´Type´ as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use reflection:

```
var formType = typeof(SomeForm); // substitute with read from dictionary

// Get ShowForm<T>
var showFormMethod = typeof(YourClass).GetMethod("ShowForm");

// Convert to ShowForm<SomeForm>
var showFormMethodSpecific = showFormMethod.MakeGenericMethod(formType);

// Call method
var yourClass = new YourClass(); // holder of ShowForm
object form = showFormMethodSpecific.Invoke(yourClass, null);

// form is now of type SomeForm
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a pretty interesting solution and it works! Unfortunately using reflection seems to be rather slow in my first tests.

Comment: What do you intend to use the dictionary for? If we knew more about what you intend to do with it, like why you have it, how you intend to fill it, etc. then perhaps I could give you a better solution.